# I want to submit three related model Forms with one submit button and render detail view

Tags: python, django

I want to admit(register) a new student with father and mother information in one form. I am able to save the father and mother form but not the student form it returns "NONE" but when i print the request.POST value I can see all the information. And I want to render a student detail with the father and mother information also but only the student information is displayed with out the father and mother info

## Model.p

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import PROTECT
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
# Student Model
class Father(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    father_pic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ASC = models.IntegerField()
    zoba = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_zoba = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField()
    parent_occupation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_guardian = models.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id = self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('student-detail', args=[str(self.id)])


class Mother(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mother_pic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ASC = models.IntegerField(default='00000')
    zoba = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_zoba = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_no = models.IntegerField()
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_guardian = models.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.id = self.id

    def __str__(self):
    
        return self.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    
        return reverse('student-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
class Student(models.Model):
    father_id = models.ForeignKey('Father', on_delete=PROTECT)
    mother_id = models.ForeignKey('Mother', on_delete=PROTECT)
    roll_no = models.IntegerField()
    admission_date = models.DateField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    student_pic = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ASC = models.IntegerField()
    zoba = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_zoba = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birth_place = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ethnicity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    DOB = models.DateField()
    guardian_is = models.BooleanField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id = self.id

    def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.first_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    """Returns the url to access a detail record for a student."""
        return reverse('student-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse
from .models import Student, Father, Mother
from django.views import generic
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponseNotFound
from .forms import StudentRegistrationForm, FatherInfo, MotherInfo


# Create your views here.
def student(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')


class StudentListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Student


class StudentDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Student
    model2 = Father
    model3 = Mother


def student_registration_view(request):
    father_id = Father.pk
    mother_id = Mother.pk
    if request.method == 'POST':
        father_form = FatherInfo(request.POST)
        mother_form = MotherInfo(request.POST)
        student_form = StudentRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if father_form.is_valid():
            father_form.save()
        # else:
        #     return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>father form is not valid</h1>')
        if mother_form.is_valid():
            mother_form.save()
        # else:
        #     return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>mother form is not valid</h1>')
        if student_form.is_valid():
            student_form.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/students')
        else:
            return HttpResponseNotFound('<h1>Student form is not valid</h1>')

    else:
        form1 = StudentRegistrationForm()
        form2 = FatherInfo()
        form3 = MotherInfo()

        context = {
            'form1': form1,
            'form2': form2,
            'form3': form3,
        }
        return render(request, 'stumgmt/student_registration.html', context=context)
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
                  path('', views.student, name="student"),
                  path('students/', views.StudentListView.as_view(), name='students'),
                  path('student/<int:pk>', views.StudentDetailView.as_view(), name='student-detail'),
                  path('student_registration/', views.student_registration_view, name='student_registration'),

              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

## student_registration.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}
  <h1 class="h1">Student Registration</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">Student Information</thead>
      {{ form1.as_table }}
    </table>
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">Father Information</thead>
    {{ form2.as_table }}
    </table>
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">Mother Information</thead>
    {{ form3.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

## forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Student, Father, Mother


class StudentRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
        # exclude = ['father_id', 'mother_id']


class FatherInfo(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Father
        fields = '__all__'


class MotherInfo(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Mother
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: You have two different question in one post. Please be more specific and ask one question per post.

Comment: Also, share what you have in your forms.py, specially, StudentRegistrationForm

Comment: Regarding to `generic.DetailView`, it doesn't have model, model2, model3. It should have only one model, or you have to dig deeply to customize it to have multiple models. Another solution is to have a normal class based view and you can handle multiple models with the way you want.

Comment: `request.POST` has all the fields together, but actually there are many fields of the same name in the 3 models, so it will be confusing for forms and they will overwrite each other. I am pretty sure that even `mother` and `father` forms are not saving correctly

Comment: Try not to save the forms separately in one view. Let's say that `father_form` is valid and `mother_form` is not valid, so `father_form` will be saved and `mother_form` will not be saved. This will cause inconsistency in your database. Moreover, you are saving `student_form` without referring to you `father` and `mother` objects.

Comment: If your purpose is to create three items in 3 tables, you can create a form which including your target field and then save them one by one after passing validation.

Comment: I separated the form validation to check which form is returning invalid and i figured out the studentregistrationform is returning none when validated together, bt  I didn't think about the inconsistency thank you for that. And I added Model2 and Model3 to access the information of father and mother of a particular student and render them on the student detail view. if its wrong(advanced) to do that how can i fetch the details of a father and mother from student_detail.html